# how to get user data from firestore react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have to get the users profile details of a specific user after they sign in using firebase. right now, it is returning the details of all of the users in my firestore.

code for getting details in Profile Page:

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';

const firestore = firebase.firestore();

class ProfilePage extends React.Component {
    state = {
        profiledata : null
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        firestore.collection('profiledata')
            // .doc("JgT2LyOB4jqhMv9YMgrh")
            .get()
            
             .then((snapshot) => {
                const profiledata  = []
                snapshot.forEach(function(doc){
                    const data = doc.data();
                    profiledata.push(data);
                }
                )
                this.setState({profiledata :  profiledata})
             })
             }
             
            render(){
        return(
            <div className='profile'>
                <h1>User</h1>
                {
                    this.state.profiledata && 
                        this.state.profiledata.map( profiledata => {
                            return(
                                <div>
                                    <p>
                                        First Name : {String(profiledata.firstname)}
                                        Last Name : {String(profiledata.lastname)}
                                        Company Name : {String(profiledata.companyname)}
                                                                        
                                        </p>
                                </div>
                                
                            )
                        })
                }
                </div>
        )
    }export default ProfilePage;
```

Here is my Output :

```
first name : john lsatname: doe company: johndoe co
first name : Lisa lsatname: doe company: lisadoe co
first name : Roger lsatname: doe company: rogerdoe co
```

There are three users in my firestore collection and it gives me in profilepage, now the problem is how can i get the specific user details based on who logs in / registers??

Any suggestions?? How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

First, You can get the current user using

`firebase.auth().currentUser;`
and then based on the uid of the user you can make a call to your firestore collection to get the other details.